# Adding Fragments to a layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to make my app more tablet-friendly, and so I'm trying to learn fragments. I want the typical two-pane layout, where the left side is the "navigation", and you click on one of the elements, and it changes the fragment on the right.

I can duplicate the tutorials that use a ListFragment for the left, and if you click on one of them, it updates the "details" fragment on the right.

I've tried the best I can to duplicate that code, and just use a LinearLayout, with buttons for the left side, so that if a button is clicked, it loads the appropriate fragment on the right, but it's not working. 
When I commit the FragmentTransaction, I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` What is the child's parent, and why do I have to call removeView on it?

I'm trying to load the fragment into a FrameLayout, but I've also just tried replacing another Fragment in the layout, and still get the error.

Ideally I want the left fragment to take up the whole screen until a button is pressed that requires a fragment to come in from the left, but one problem at a time I suppose.

### Code

#### Main Activity

```
public class FragmentExample2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

#### SelectorFragment (Left side)

```
public class SelectorFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, container);

        Button button1 = (Button) fragment.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail_holder, new DetailsFragment(), "stuff").commit();

            }

        });


        return fragment;
    }
}
```

#### DetailsFragment

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container);
    }
}
```

#### main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <fragment class="com.coreno.testfragment.SelectorFragment"
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <fragment class="com.coreno.testfragment.DetailsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/detail_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
    <!-- 
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_holder" 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
 -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you inflate a layout xml file, don't specify the parent view. It sounds very counter-intuitive to not specify where you're putting this inflated view but it works.

So, for example, in your SelectorFragment change the line:

```
View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, container);
```

to

```
View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, null);
```

or even better

```
View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, container, false);
```

Don't forget to do the same in your DetailsFragment too.

Comment: Ah hah! I don't have to bang my head against the wall anymore! Thank you very much, that worked!

Comment: In the above code, the layout xml file returns a view.That's a LinearLayout,RelativeLayout with some textview or webview something like that. If I am creating the view progrmatically like LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this); in some method and call that method and get as view.Then how can I inflate this layout.?

Answer (score 8):

When you inflate a layout inside the getView method of a Fragment, you must use the next inflate method:
inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, **false**);

The key is the third parameter. It must be false not to attach the inflated layout to the container, because the system already done it. If it is true or is not indicated a redundant group view is created.